# French Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, french

Could someone help me to write a bibliography in french? I tried many codes for this site (copy/paste in a separate document) and I always get errors. 
e.g. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Start by omitting `.bib` from the argument of `\bibliography`. Then rerun LaTeX, BibTeX (you did run it before, right?), and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to see what's happening in your example, but I don't think it has anything to do with language. Here's a good place to start learning about your options creating your bibliography:
[biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners)

(There are some choices to be made between bibtex and biber packages, outside both the scope of my answer *and* my knowledge.)

Using myself (a LaTeX beginner) as an example -- I use a free service called Mendeley (JabRef, Docear are others) to organize my article library of PDFs; it offers an export to .bib format (I call mine *Mendeley2016Memoire.bib*). Then I put this "database file" into the same directory with my .tex files, add the package in my preamble which looks like this:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear,
style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Mendeley2016Memoire.bib}
\addbibresource{original.bib}
```

Note - if you're using backend of bibtex things look different ... you'll lose the .bib extension, specify resources differently.

I've then been citing references using \autocite{} but others have stronger opinions here.

That's a start I hope -- bon courage.

Comment: I think the OP already has all the required packages and just forgot to run BibTeX.

Comment: A link to kno how to actually set the editor up to use `biber` would be good in your answer.